# Spivak Chapter 8, Problem 11b: Analytical proof of relationship between circle area and areas of inscribed polygons with $n$ and $2n$ sides.

Tags: calculus, alternative-proof

This is from a problem in Spivak's Calculus. It is in the chapter on least upper bounds, though this particular item of a problem is related to geometry.

> 11b) Suppose $P$ is a regular polygon inscribed inside a circle. If
> $P'$ is the inscribed regular polygon with twice as many sides, show
> that the difference between the area of the circle and the area of the
> $P'$ is less than half the difference between the area of the circle
> and the area of $P$.

This is easy to show using a geometric argument:

[image]

We want to show that

$$R_2 < \frac{1}{2}(R_1+R_2)$$

$$R_2<R_1$$

This is clearly true because $R_2<R_2+R_3=R_1$.

**I'd like an analytical proof.** Below I will simply show what I did, but it's a path that didn't lead me to an answer, feel free to ignore it.

Here is what I thought was leading to the correct conclusion but actually not.

$A_1=\frac{b_1h_1}{2}$

$A_2=\frac{b_2h_2}{2}$

$\sin{\left (\frac{\alpha}{2} \right )}=\frac{b_1}{r}$

$b_1 = r \sin{\left (\frac{\alpha}{2} \right )}\tag{1}$

$\cos{\left (\frac{\alpha}{2} \right )} = \frac{h_1}{r}$

$$h_1 = r\cos{\left (\frac{\alpha}{2} \right )}\tag{2}$$

Therefore, $$A_1 = \frac{r^2 \sin{\left (\frac{\alpha}{2} \right )} \cos{\left (\frac{\alpha}{2} \right )}}{2}\tag{3}$$

$\sin{\beta}=\frac{b_1}{b_2}$

$$b_1 = b_2 \sin{\beta}\tag{4}$$

From $(1)$ and $(4)$

$$r \sin{\left (\frac{\alpha}{2} \right )} = b_2\sin{\beta}$$
$$b_2 = \frac{r \sin{\left (\frac{\alpha}{2} \right )}}{\sin{\beta}}\tag{5}$$

$\sin{\beta}=\frac{h_2}{r}$

$$h_2 = r \sin{\beta}\tag{6}$$

From $(5)$ and $(6)$

$$A_2 = \frac{r^2 \sin{\left (\frac{\alpha}{2} \right )}}{2}\tag{7}$$

Therefore,

$$A_1=A_2 \cos{\left (\frac{\alpha}{2} \right )}$$

But an inscribed polygon has $n \geq 3$ sides.

$$\alpha = \frac{2\pi}{n}, n \geq 3$$

$$0 < \alpha < \frac{2\pi}{3}$$

$$0 < \frac{\alpha}{2} < \frac{\pi}{3}$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \leq \cos{\left (\frac{\alpha}{2} \right )} < 1$$

$$\frac{A_2}{2} \leq A_2 \cos{\left (\frac{\alpha}{2} \right )} < A_2$$

$$\frac{A_2}{2} \leq A_1 < A_2$$

So we know that $A_1$ is more than half as large as $A_2$, and smaller than $A_2$

$$-A_2 < -A_1 \leq -\frac{A_2}{2}$$

$$\pi r^2-A_2 < \pi r^2-A_1 \leq \pi r^2-\frac{A_2}{2}\tag{8}$$

$(8)$ doesn't seem quite right.

[image]

[image]

Comment: From the algebraic-geometry tag description: "This tag should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry."

Comment: Did Spivak prove a formula for the area of a circle sector?

Comment: No, I believe not. Which is why my attempt is also wrong I believe.